# Не получается сделать SELECT FROM SELECT [MS SQL Server]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Есть таблица Сотрудники (Employees) и Отделы (Departments).
Необходимо найти такие отделы, в которых суммарная зарплата сотрудников будет наибольшей.
Вот наполнение самих таблиц

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дошел только до того, что нашел максимальную сумму

```
SELECT MAX(A.SUM_Money)
FROM (
    SELECT Dep_number, SUM(Cash_bonus + Salary) AS SUM_Money
    FROM Employees
    GROUP BY Dep_number
) AS A
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только вот никак не могу вывести рядом поле с номером отдела

```
SELECT A.Dep_number, MAX(A.SUM_Money)
FROM (
    SELECT Dep_number, SUM(Cash_bonus + Salary) AS SUM_Money
    FROM Employees
    GROUP BY Dep_number
) AS A
```

Пишет ошибку:

Сообщение 8120, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 3

Столбец "A.Dep_number" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в статистической функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY.

Подскажите как быть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще, группировка должна быть в том запросе, в котором используется аггрегация. Так что запрос будет таким:

```
SELECT A.Dep_number, MAX(A.SUM_Money)
FROM (
    SELECT Dep_number, SUM(Cash_bonus + Salary) AS SUM_Money
    FROM Employees
    GROUP BY Dep_number
) AS A
GROUP BY A.Dep_Number.
```

Но это не то, что нам нужно, поскольку для каждого Dep_Number у нас в запросе только одна запись.
Можно просто отсортировать по SUM_Money по убыванию и взять первую запись:

```
SELECT TOP 1 A.Dep_number, A.SUM_Money
FROM (
    SELECT Dep_number, SUM(Cash_bonus + Salary) AS SUM_Money
    FROM Employees
    GROUP BY Dep_number
) AS A
ORDER BY A.SUM_Money DESC
```

Но отделов с одинаковой суммой может быть несколько. Поэтому добавим ранжирование в подзапрос:

```
    SELECT A.Dep_number, A.SUM_Money
    FROM (
        SELECT rank() over(order by sum(cash_bonus+Salary) desc) rank, 
        Dep_number, SUM(Cash_bonus + Salary) AS SUM_Money
        FROM Employees
        GROUP BY Dep_number
    ) AS A
where rank=1
```

[фиддл](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/720782/7)